# Why UL and why not OL?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why we always use <ul> to make Navigation why not <ol> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775200/why-we-always-use-ul-to-make-navigation-why-not-ol)

Why Designers always use ul for menu and many things else and why they don't use ol for menu and etc.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ol implies you want an ordered list, e.g. numbered 1,2,3 or I, II, III.  generally for menu navigation you wouldn't want to number your menu items.  so instead use a ul and apply CSS to get the layout you want.  But often I will use OL e.g. if outputting a numbered list of terms and conditions.

Answer (score 5):

ul means unordered, ol means ordered.

Most people percieve a menu as having no obvious numerical order. If you were marking up a 5 star rating system of something, then ol would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In most websites, the order you read pages in is not important. An ol would be suitable for a collection of pages that should be read in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, `ul` stands for "unordered list", while `ol` means an "ordered list".

My reasoning why menu items can be seen as unordered is that one menu or menu item is *logically* independent from the others; the order of menu items doesn't really matter. Everything would still be perfectly reasonable and understandable if menu items were swapped.

That being said, a particular ordering of the menu items is usually still desirable; but that is not a question of logical content, but one of presentation, so it's proper and sufficient to just list the items in the desired order in the HTML document.

(Remember that mark-up such as `ul` and `ol` ideally relates to content, not to presentation.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out: [Why do we always use `<ul>` to make Navigation, why not `<ol>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775200/why-we-always-use-ul-to-make-navigation-why-not-ol)

Comment: you should mark the question for closing as an exact duplicate of that link

Comment: i do..................................................