# Why are <ul> commonly used to build website navigation?

Tags: html, list, css

Why are unordered lists commonly used to build website navigation opposed to using ordered lists or simply creating div id's that are placed in an another id element as a group?  Maybe its a leftover from previous versions of html/css that I am too young to remember, or maybe a result of increased CSS3 control, but I've always done it this way and never really questioned why:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nav Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The beauty of this system is that it allows indexing engines like google to understand that all of those items in the list are related.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775200/why-we-always-use-ul-to-make-navigation-why-not-ol

Comment: I always thought, with all the semantic tags being created that there should be a `<menuitem>` or something. Yes a menu can be technically be considered a list, but in most cases it is not displayed as one.

Comment: @John — There is `<nav>` which is for holding navigation content. If you navigation content is a list of links, it should be a list of links within a nav element.

Comment: We can look forward to a future where we will be able to simply use `nav` and `a` in order to semantically group a set of related menu items. The extra `li` tags won't be needed anymore, which will be great since a typical menu uses CSS to override the list presentation anyway. I have a feeling there will soon be scripts that take minimal markup, like markdown, and automatically enrich it into `section`s, `summary`(ies), `header`s, `article`s, and `nav` menus, and plain text web authoring will become effective and popular again like the good old pre-WYSIWYG days of HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A menu is a list of links.

Since it is a list it should be represented using list markup, and not generic block (div) markup.

From [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html):

> Note. CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.

Most websites present a list of sections but the order in which you visit them does not matter. This means the order of the list items is not significant so it should be an unordered list of links and not an ordered list of links.

Comment: This is the common thinking which I agree with. However, there's some debate: http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Comment: @helion3 from the post you provide I see this beautiful word **heirarchy** I go with ul just for that :)

Comment: @helion3 — Looking at the Listless Nav in that item without CSS makes it very hard to see where one link ends and the next begins. Trying it in a browser that doesn't underline links (such as Lynx, which runs on a console and can't render underlines) makes it impossible. That's a terrible idea.

Comment: I do as well. I can't remember the last time I used anything but lists for navigation

Comment: I'm not advocating for this stuff, just pointing out that lists are not entirely unanimous.

Comment: @helion3 — The follow up article from the same author came to the conclusion that lists are the right approach.

Comment: I suppose that using lists makes it easier to create and target sub menus, which I feel are largely disappearing as a result of the rise of responsive/mobile websites, and their lack of usability in those platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The *historical* reason (which is what you seem to want) is that, about ten years ago, web standard advocates such as [Jeffery Zeldman](http://books.google.com/books?id=hVsCia9J8XEC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=%22web+standards%22+%22unordered+list%22+zeldman&source=bl&ots=DfUvGpV7KW&sig=r4vGm6xhVycU0ChQLan8HkKLAL0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0UT1UpSmDcOYyAHxsYCICg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22web%20standards%22%20%22unordered%20list%22%20zeldman&f=false) heavily promoted designing navigation menus that way. I particularly remember reading [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists/) that recommended the style.

One of the big ideas motivating the web standards movement was the separation of presentation from content. So, you would not want to use (X)HTML to control how the menu is rendered. The other main idea was that markup should respect the semantics of the document. That is to say, the markup should mean something in the context of the document. Since a menu is just a list, `ul/li` was the most obvious choice *at the time*.